# Format polynomial to normal form> (How to let the final result become string in lisp?(all functions included))

Tags: string, loops, printing, lisp, common-lisp

I am current writing a function about the input P is a PExpr in normal form. Output a string representing P in the following "common sense" format

here is what I got for now：

```
(defun writepoly (a b start)
  (cond
    ((and (minusp a) start) 
      (princ "-"))
    ((not start)
      (princ (if (plusp a) " + " " - "))))

  (cond
    ((not (equal (abs a) 1))
    (princ (abs a))))

  (cond
    ((equal (abs b) 1)
      (princ "x"))
    ((> (abs b) 1)
      (princ "x")
      (princ "^")
      (princ b))))


(defun print-pexpr (P)
(loop for (a . b) in P
  for start = t then nil

    do (write-to-string (writepoly a b start))
```

I did get the correct result, like

```
(print-pexpr '((-1 . 10) (-23 . 0)))

-x^10 - 23
NIL
```

but when I do the test case

```
(defun test-case (ID Test Result)
    (if (equal Test Result)
        (format nil "Test ~S OK" ID)
        (format nil "FAIL: Test ~S expected ~S got ~S" ID Result Test)
    )
   )

(test-case 6.4
    (print-pexpr '((-1 . 10) (-23 . 0)))
    "-x^10 - 23"
)
```

the output is :

```
"FAIL: Test 6.4 expected \"-x^10 - 23\" got NIL
```

how to change my function so that I could get string...? should I not use princ command? Hope someone could answer my question...thank you

PS: I copied the method in [Lisp Formatting Polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327668/lisp-formatting-polynomial)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions like `princ`, `print`, ecc. perform two different tasks:

1. They print their argument on the standard output, which normally is the terminal, but can be something different if the special variable `*standard-output*` is rebound;
2. They return the argument printed as a language value.

For instance:

```
CL-USER> (+ (print 1) (print 2))

1   ; <- printed by (print 1), which returns also 1
2   ; <- printed by (print 2), which returns also 2
3   ; <- the sum of 1+2, printed by the REPL, not by the program!
```

So, if you try for instance `(writepoly -1 10 t)` you get:

```
CL-USER> (writepoly -1 10 t)
-x^10   ; <- printed by writepoly
10      ; <- returned by writepoly
```

In other words, your program prints something and returns something else, like the last function, in which you print the polynomial but return NIL (as clear by reading the two lines after the call `print-pexpr`), and this is the cause of the error.

How can be modified the program to return the string printed? Basically there are two possibility. The first is that suggested by the answer of Rainer Joswing, using two things: the function [`with-output-to-string`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_w_out_.htm#with-output-to-string), that creates a new output stream, in which everything that is “printed” is returned at the end as a single string, the second by giving as name of that stream `*standard-output*`, which in practice “instruct” all the print command (without an explicit stream parameter) to print on that string (otherwise you should change all the print call by adding explicitly the stream on which to print).

So you could change your last function with:

```
(defun print-pexpr (P)
  (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
    (loop for (a . b) in P
      for start = t then nil
      do (writepoly a b start))))
```

An alternative way is that, instead of printing the result to some stream, to transform it in a string by using [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_format.htm#format) with first parameter `NIL`, instead of print, (like for instance `(format () "~a" expression)`), and then [`concatenate`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_concat.htm#concatenate) all those string into a single one when combining the different parts (using again `format` or `concatenate`). This requires more changes to your program.

Answer (score 2):

```
CL-USER 6 > (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
              (princ 'foobar))
"FOOBAR"
```